# Fail to collect coverage for java maven projects with Intellij IDE

Tags: java, maven, junit, code-coverage

I wanted to collect coverage info, but the error message is "At least 5 arguments expected but 1 found."
I'm using IntelliJ IDE and maven projects and the Junit test framework.
[image]
[image]

Also, I noticed that the path of the first argument includes illegal characters, which are not in English and are part of the user name of my computer.

Alternatively, when I switched to Jacoco coverage tool instead of the tool provided by Intellij, the problem was "File Not Found Exception", the path of the file contained illegal characters.

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling Intellij.

I really do not know how to solve it; I would appreciate it if anyone could give me some help.

[image]

Now I configured Jacoco in the POM file for my maven project and ran maven commands to collect code coverage.

Comment: Is the attribute `Person.age` accessible ? Is that attribute declared public?

Comment: Yes, it is declared public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I found is to rename windows user. It is a painful operation with modification of regisrty.

Here is the instruction in Russian.

https://zen.yandex.ru/media/tehnichka/kak-pereimenovat-papku-polzovatelia-v-windows-10-5ffc31e6fe4e686f6ab950f5

May be you will find the same in English.

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer is to the point and quite helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Non-ascii chars are exist in tmp path.

1. Open the IDEA, click: `Help` -> `Edit Custom VM Options`
2. Insert a record `-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\\tmp` or other path with ascii chars only.
3. Restart IDEA.

Solition is described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4402863714066/comments/4408432573586).

Answer (score 0):

As exception suggests your attempt to run with coverage has leak of sufficient argument to be executed, namely

- Directory to save test coverage result
- Flag for identify the tracking per test
- Flag to how calculate empty [classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000B2UEIA0)
- Flag for how to use data files
- Flag to indicate to run coverage in sampling (or tracing) mode

You can follow the official documentation for setting [coverages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html#run-config-with-coverage) in run configuration and passing required arguments regard to your case.

Comment: Hi, I appricate your help.  I followed the documentation, but it does not work. I guess it's because of the illegal character issue, but I do not know. I also tried Jacoco here; the problem is different. I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try path File -> Invalidate Caches -> clear file system cache and local history -> invalidate and restart. Maybe it will work.